# Display Instragram pictures with http://instafeedjs.com/

Tags: javascript, html

I try to get my latest imagefrom my Instagramm Feed using http://instafeedjs.com/
I get the plugin working as I can see in the console that my images get fetched, BUT they don't get displayed somehow.
My code is following

> ```
>     <script type="text/javascript">
> var userFeed = new Instafeed({
>     get: 'user',
>     userId: '12345',
>     accessToken: '123456'
> });
> userFeed.run();
> ```

Any clues what I overlooked to make the script display the latest image from my feed? Or an any image at all?

Comment: Do you have `<div id="instafeed"></div>` in your page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the `<div id="instafeed"></div>` placed in your html somewhere? If not, add it!

Comment: sorry, I had a typo in the div,... so sorry for that. And thanks for pointing me at the div

Comment: No problem at all. We all know these things happen when coding stuff. I'm glad you got it working :)

Comment: Yeah, you can just add an option to your script `sortBy: 'most-recent'`and you'll be there ;) And `limit: 1`if you want just one photo